# VBA gives Error upon opening PPT in MAC OS

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I use VBA to export data from XL to PPT. In windows it works fine. But When I use same code in MAC OS. I get error in this line..
`Set pPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(currentPath & Application.PathSeparator & pptname, msoFalse, msoCTrue, msoCTrue)`

```
Dim pptApp As Object


Dim pPres As Object
Dim xl As Excel.Workbooks


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sldrange As Object
Dim sld As Object
Dim pattrenSlide As Object

Dim WorkSheetRange As Range

Sub Export()
'both file names and path
Dim wkname, pptname, currentPath As String


'Other Values

pptname = "Template.pptx"
currentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path


'Ópening Powerpoint
Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set pPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(currentPath & Application.PathSeparator & pptname, msoFalse, msoCTrue, msoCTrue)
'Opening Excel
Set wk = ThisWorkbook
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is the error you encounter?

Comment: Hello, error i get: Method "Open" of object "Presentation" failed

Comment: You're probably running into MacBrickWall, aka Apple's sandboxing requirements.  Have a look here for possible solutions:  https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/index.html